# ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec

Tags: r-markdown, xelatex, tinytex, fontspec

I am trying to generate pdf from **rmarkdown** file using **xelatex** as latex engine. The file generates pdf while using pdflatex as latex engine. But, if I use xelatex, the file is giving the following error.

`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile cvGeneration.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See cvGeneration.log for more info.
Execution halted`

When I checked the log file I got the following few lines only.

*`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.65 ...Package[\eu@zf@math]{fontspec}[2008/08/09]

The package fontspec has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [no-math]
Adding the global options:
  ,no-math
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing    to proceed.`*

Can anyone tell me why this problem is generating particularly for xelatex? I am trying to implement xelatex, since it supports UTF-8 character.
Thanks In advance.

My YAML header is given below:

```
  params:
  cvName: RJ MIMI
  name: "`r params$cvName`"
  address: 
  www: 
  phone:
  email: 
  linkedin: 
  headcolor: "00008B"
  date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B')`"
  output:
    vitae::hyndman:
      keep_tex: true
      latex_engine: xelatex
  header_includes:
    - \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{useprefix=true}
    - renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{12.4}\sffamily}
```

Comment: Do you load further Latex packages in your YAML header? Can you provide your YAML header?

Comment: @J_F The header YAML is added with the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty far down the road, however, the easiest way to get past the `fontspec` error is to set `defaultfontfeatures`. (`fontspec` is the default in RMarkdown.)

I don't have all that is going into your code here, update your `header_includes` to:

```
header_includes:
    - \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{useprefix=true}
    - \defaultfontfeatures(Ligatures = TeX)
    - renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{12.4}\sffamily}
```

This may still give you warnings because it's not *right*, but it works.